# Can i use HSV color space to segment various colors and shapes of road signs?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

If i have the following types of signs is it possible to use 1 technique that will work for each sign to be extracted alone in real time life scenes ?

[image: road signs]

Comment: what do you mean with "extracted alone"? of course you can use the Hue channel of HSV to do color segmentation, but you'll get everything that shares the same colours as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to find and extract these signs, you can try something like histogram of oriented gradient based template matching.  You can use template matching available in opencv.

Also, It can be done using hsv color space but that would not be a robust solution, as it will depend on environmental factors like lighting etc..